# Extending a model of a multi-sorted algebraic theory by at least one element

Tags: abstract-algebra, logic, model-theory

Let $\mathbb{T}$ be a multi-sorted algebraic theory (i.e. a set of equations between terms over a multi-sorted signature with function symbols and constants). In particular, I am interested in the case where $\mathbb{T}$ has at least two sorts. For any model $M$ of $\mathbb{T}$ and any sort $A$ of $\mathbb{T}$, let $M_A$ be the set that interprets this sort in $M$.

I am interested in the following question: is there a condition that can be put on $\mathbb{T}$ to guarantee that if $M$ is any model of $\mathbb{T}$ such that $|M_A| \leq 1$ for some sort $A$, then there will be a model $N$ of $\mathbb{T}$ such that $|N_A| \geq 2$ and there is a homomorphism $h : M \to N$?

Or, to state the question in another (not necessarily equivalent) way, if $M\langle x_A \rangle$ is the coproduct of $M$ with the free $\mathbb{T}$-model on one generator $x_A$ of sort $A$, can we impose some condition on $\mathbb{T}$ to guarantee that $|M\langle x_A \rangle_A| \geq 2$?

For example, would it be sufficient to assume that $\mathbb{T}$ does not prove that the sort $A$ is trivial, in the sense that $\mathbb{T} \not\vdash x = x'$ for distinct variables $x, x'$ of sort $A$?

Comment: It's not enough to assume that $\mathbb{T}$ does not prove that $A$ is trivial. For example, the theory of rings does not prove $x = x'$, but the zero ring does not admit a homomorphism into any non-zero ring. More generally, it's possible to have a model $M$ where $M_A = \{a\}$ and $\mathbb{T}$ together with the diagram of $M$ proves $x = a$.

Comment: Hmm, okay, thanks for this counter-example.

Comment: Such behavior is even possible when $M_B$ is empty. Consider a theory with sorts $A$ and $B$, constants $0$ and $1$ is sort $A$, and a binary function $f\colon A\times B\to B$. The axioms are $f(0,x) = f(0,y)$ and $f(1,x) = x$. Let $M$ be a model where $M_A = \{*\}$, $M_B = \emptyset$, and the symbols have their only possible interpretations. In particular, $0 = 1$ in $M$. Now if $h\colon M\to N$ is a homomorphism, then $0 = 1$ in $N$, and then we have for all $b,b'\in N_B$, $b = f(1,b) = f(0,b) = f(0,b') = f(1,b') = b'$, so $|N_B|\leq 1$.